# I have read all the songs from external storage by using MediaStore.Audio.Media. But I cannot extract uri of the song

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, uri, android-mediaplayer

I am reading songs by this way:

```
 private void getMusic() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = contentResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int musicTitleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int musicArtistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int musicPathColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
            String musicTitle = musicCursor.getString(musicTitleColumn);
            String musicArtist = musicCursor.getString(musicArtistColumn);
            String musicPath = musicCursor.getString(musicPathColumn);
            mList.add(new MusicData(musicTitle, musicArtist, musicPath, R.drawable.image));
        } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

in code above I used MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA to extract the path of the song. But it is not working with MediaPlayer.

I am using MediaPlayer like this:

```
  String path = songData.getMusicPath();
  MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), Uri.parse(path));
            if (player != null) {
                player.start();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: `Uri.parse(path)`. Please give an example of a value for path. Also tell the value for Uri.parse(path).toString() for that example.

Comment: Uri.parse(path).toString() this returns "storage/emulated/0/Music/Lullaby-Sigala.m4a"

Comment: It should give "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Lullaby-Sigala.m4a". The value for path too.

Comment: `But I cannot extract uri of the song` What do you mean by that?